# Resuming with the same activity on device configuration change

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an activity. When I change the orientation, onCreate is called as we know. A new activity is created. But I want to continue with my old activity, is there a way to restore the old one and continue with it?

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your activity tag

```
android:configChanges="orientation"
```

Comment: android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"   I have this in my manifest, but still I have the same issue

Comment: override onConfigChange method in ur activity

Comment: I did it. I'm just asking to keep and resume with the same activity, you offer me solutions which are not related to my case.